# Area transformation

Tags: geometry, triangles, applications

I have two rows of different types A and B. Every row is of the size 1$\times$N, where every element can be either 1 or -1.

If we consider a single row of type A={-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,...} of size 1$\times$N, I am processing this row by dot product with the following row 'mask' of size 1$\times$N.

mask(x) - $Equation(1.1)$:$$\frac{2}{N(N+1)}\sum_{n=1}^{N}N+1-x$$

Now, I change this mask by a factor 'b' and 'c' if the row type is A and B respectively. Thus, the shape of this mask (original in black and changed in blue for A, pink for B) would look like:

[image]

Now, if I have a row of 1$\times$N, where there are P elements are of type A and Q elements are of type B (is where I am stuck).

I tried the following:

I changed the mask of length P modifying N in equation 1.1 to N/2) and used the blue mask for first P elements and pink mask for next Q elements. Now, I am not sure how to add them up.

I think it would be on mapping the blue and pink area to the original triangle formed by black lines. But not sure how to relate them exactly.

[image]

Any hints or guide will be helpful.